# What does clipping gaussian noise mean?

Tags: noise

I found the subject at here like this "Does clipping noise colour the spectrum"
When I researching for clipping noise.

But I can't understand because typically something has clipped means something has removed.
But he has some different point of view about this.
so I want to know what is the clipping noise and how to undertand the posing about "Does clipping noise colour the spectrum"?

## update

Especially, I want to know the meanning  about clipping gaussian noise.

Especially this part
IV. CLIPPING (CENSORING)
A. Clipped observations model

Comment: There were lots of these questions lately... Clipping occurs, when the amplitude is exceeding the bounds in digital domain. For example when using 16 bit data, you must fit everything between -32768:32767. You amplify to much - you clip. And that is distorting the amplitude. What is the clipping noise then? I am sure you can take it from here.

Comment: Clipping is a _nonlinear_ operation and while _something_ is being removed  by the clipping, what is removed is not what is being measured when you measure the spectrum. As a general rule, one gets an output signal with _larger_ bandwidth when the input to the clipper is processed

Comment: noise is an (unwanted) signal whereas clipping is a distortion. When a good signal is clipped it becomes severley (irrecoverably  and nonlinearly) distorted and bad. When noise is added to a clear signal it becomes degraded and dirty. When a noise signal is clipped then possibly the clipping noise happens... :) The clipping operation, because of its very nonlinear character, has the tendency to add rich harmonics to the signal, which may be is why it is defined as a coloring opearation on the noise spectrum

Comment: @Fat32 Thanks , But I think the clipping is that some signal have reboundary interval. For example,I think the clipping signal opertation which is If a signal have 0~255, then the clipping signal is 50~200. It's means that 0~49 and 201~255 is to be 0. For another example is that sine wave going to rectangular wave by clipped from sine wave.

Comment: In the context of the OP's question, the concept of "clipping noise" is an aid to model and understand clipping. If the signal's allowed range is [0,255], but the actual signal is $s=-2,258,257$, we can think of the clipped signal as $s_c=s+n_c$, where the "clipping noise" $n_c=2,-3,-2$.

Comment: @Mbaz in the context of signal processing, the error resulting from clipping is considered to be a distortion and not a noise, however one is of course free to call his signals whatever way he finds appropriate as either a distortion or a noise. May be they are extending the termninology from Quantization noise model to clipping noise in a similar manner..

Comment: @Fat32 Sir, is this gaussian noise clipping same concept above noise clipping?

Comment: I dont think if it would change based on noise type.

Comment: White noise, Gaussian or not, won't be "colored" by clipping. Instead, the clipping only changes the probability density functions of the independent instantaneous signal values. That's still going to be white noise.

Comment: @Olli I very hard hear your comment

Comment: Maybe your question should be about "clipping of noise" rather than "clipping noise". Usually, clipping means that the clipped values are not set to zero but to some max or min value.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo how did you infer "White" noise from his question..? OP never says anything about an iid white noise... ?

Comment: It's a special case with an easy answer so I stated the case and the answer.

Comment: @gmotree What is the first sentence in " IV. CLIPPING (CENSORING) A. Clipped observations model" that you don't understand?

Comment: @niaren no i can't :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your noise has independent and identically distributed samples from a zero-mean distribution (for example Gaussian), it is white. Other definitions of white noise also require the distribution to be symmetrical, but that is not required for the spectrum to be flat. Clipping the samples of such white noise will only change the common probability distribution of the samples:

[image: clipping of a probability density function]

This will affect the mean of the distribution, but if both sides are clipped in a way that preserves the zero mean of the distribution, then there is no "coloring" of the spectrum by a 0 Hz peak and the noise remains white.

Example in Octave (MATLAB clone):

Create random variables from a Gaussian distribution:

```
N = 65536;
x = normrnd(zeros(N, 1), ones(N, 1));
```

Clip from above:

```
y = min(x, 1);
```

Clip symmetrically from below:

```
z = max(y, -1);
```

Plot values of Gaussian random variables (blue), clipped above (green), clipped symmetrically (red). Horizontal axis = index, vertical axis = value:

```
plot(1:N, x, 1:N, y, 1:N, z)
```

[image: Plot values of Gaussian random variables (blue), clipped above (green), clipped symmetrically (red). Horizontal axis = index, vertical axis = value]

Plot spectrum of Gaussian random variables (blue), clipped above (green), clipped symmetrically (red). Horizontal axis = frequency, vertical axis = magnitude:

```
loglog(1:N/2, abs(fft(x)(1:N/2)), 1:N/2, abs(fft(y)(1:N/2)), 1:N/2, abs(fft(z)(1:N/2)));
```

[image: Plot spectrum of Gaussian random variables (blue), clipped above (green), clipped symmetrically (red). Horizontal axis = frequency, vertical axis = magnitude]

The sequence that was clipped from above has a spectral peak at 0 Hz. Otherwise, the spectral envelopes are flat. This is not very easy to see because of the increasing density of plot points in the high frequencies in the logarithmic scale plot.

Comment: I guess from his question that OP is not talking about a white noise... May be he should make it clear...

Comment: @Fat32 yes I am talking about a gaussian noise clipping.

Comment: Gaussian noise can be white. Yours isn't?

Comment: Hmm i think white is flat . It has not distiribution

Comment: White means that the spectrum is flat. Sample values (in time domain) can follow for example the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @Olli Niemitalo Can you give to me concrete example? If you have matlab it is too fine.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: @Olli Thanks , but I can't get what's your point?  I think that you want tell me, if we clip the white flat noise, the white noise is no longer flat. Am I wrong?

Comment: It depends. If you clip it so that the mean of the sample value distribution remains 0, the expected spectrum of the noise process remains flat. If you clip it so that the mean of the distribution becomes non-zero, the spectrum will no longer be flat but will have a higher peak at 0 Hz. The rest of the spectrum remains flat.